# Authenticate web users against Tivoli with PHP (SSO)

Tags: php, single-sign-on, tivoli

we have a PHP webapp here that needs to be integrated into the company's Single Sign On.

- Is it generally possible to authenticate users against Tivoli web access manager with PHP?
- Are there existing open source libs/frameworks for that?
- Can anyone point me to a good tutorial for beginners about this topic?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean Tivoli Access Manager for e-business, typically, your PHP web app would be 'junctioned' behind a WebSEAL instance.  WebSEAL would be responsible for authenticating the end user against the TAM directory and the user's identity would be propagated down the junction to the web app. This can be achieved using a number of different techniques (see this [old] article but its still relevant: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/ITAME/SC32-1134-01/en_US/HTML/amweb41_admin11.htm). It'd be the web app's responsibility to consume the identity that is used in the SSO.

The following article explains some of the SSO techniques is in terms of a portal environment:  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/tivoli/library/t-ssocandc/index.html.